# Using SideMenu Pod for navigation causes bugs when changing screens

Tags: swift3, sidebar

[image]I am using this pod: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu for my Side bar in my app. I set the side bar navigation through Storyboard. My app design is that I have a main screen, and a side bar with buttons that take me to different screens. The different screens also have the same side bar. My bug is in this situation: I go into the side bar from main screen -> Then I go into screen2 through the side bar -> I click on the side bar from the screen 2 -> Side bar appears from the bottom and takes the whole screen.
For fixing this bug I found a workaround that does NOT satisfy me. I understood I need to dismiss the side bar but then if I want to go into another screen I first see the screen I came from (because I dismiss) and then it only moves to the second screen. I hope this makes sense. I want to achieve switching to the second screen without first seeing the main screen. This is the code that helps me dismiss and then change screens:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    goIncident()
})

func goIncident(){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let window = appDelegate.window
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "log") as! UINavigationController

     window?.rootViewController = rootController
}
```

Edit: The added photo shows the problem when I only use the function `goIncident()` without dismissing. If I do dissmiss, I see the home screen and only after the home screen is presented when it calls the new screen to appear.

Comment: Add screenshot also

Comment: Alright, few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used a very ugly method to solve this, but I believe this is the only possible way, since this Pod is not very flexible, unless I missed something. What I did is this:

In `SideBarViewController`:

```
func goLog(){
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "changeLog"), object: self)
}
```

In `MainViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(goLog), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "changeLog"), object: nil)
}

func goLog(){
    let logViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IncidentLogViewController") as! IncidentLogViewController    
    self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [logViewController]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "dismissSideBar"), object: self)

}
```

So the Side bar tells the navigation controller to replace its view controller, and then after its replaced the navigation controller send back a notification to dismiss the the side bar. Pretty ugly but actually works smoothly.